# Why is `rpm -qa base*` so terribly slow?

Tags: rpm, performance

I wonder:
`rpm` uses a (simple) database to store things like packet names.
When using `rpm -qa` to query that database, it is terribly slow.

For example, this command took almost a minute to complete while the disk was "shuffling":

```sh
# rpm -qa rtl8812au-kmp\*
rtl8812au-kmp-preempt-5.9.3.2+git20210427.6ef5d8f_k5.3.18_57-lp153.1.1.x86_64
rtl8812au-kmp-default-5.9.3.2+git20210427.6ef5d8f_k5.3.18_57-lp153.1.1.x86_64
```

Of course the second invocation was much faster, as all the data was in disk cache, so it took 2.2 seconds "only".
Fast is spelled differently, however.

```sh
# grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz     : 3998.528
...
# LANG= time dd if=/var/lib/rpm/Packages of=/dev/null
748816+0 records in
748816+0 records out
383393792 bytes (383 MB, 366 MiB) copied, 0.606612 s, 632 MB/s
0.30user 0.29system 0:00.60elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1876maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+81minor)pagefaults 0swaps
# LANG= time rpm -qa rtl8812au-kmp\*
rtl8812au-kmp-preempt-5.9.3.2+git20210427.6ef5d8f_k5.3.18_57-lp153.1.1.x86_64
rtl8812au-kmp-default-5.9.3.2+git20210427.6ef5d8f_k5.3.18_57-lp153.1.1.x86_64
2.17user 0.06system 0:02.24elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 32472maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+6302minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

So reading the complete package (names) database completely is faster than searching for a specific name!

The `/var` (root) filesystem is `ext3` put on an LV where the PV of the VG is a LUKS-encrypted volume make from a partition of a RAID1 (imsm):

```sh
# hdparm -t /dev/mapper/system-root
/dev/mapper/system-root:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 242 MB in  3.02 seconds =  80.19 MB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/mapper/cr_md-uuid-fe1588c4:a2140388:5b4117ba:4e4339b9-part5
/dev/mapper/cr_md-uuid-fe1588c4:a2140388:5b4117ba:4e4339b9-part5:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 240 MB in  3.03 seconds =  79.33 MB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-fe1588c4:a2140388:5b4117ba:4e4339b9-part5
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-fe1588c4:a2140388:5b4117ba:4e4339b9-part5:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 290 MB in  3.01 seconds =  96.32 MB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 408 MB in  3.01 seconds = 135.63 MB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 394 MB in  3.01 seconds = 130.92 MB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 444 MB in  3.03 seconds = 146.61 MB/sec
```

### Timing example

Sorry, this is a late addition, but I had to remember to make the timing test after boot before the RPM database files are in cache.

```bash
~> time rpm -qa libavd\*
libavdevice58_13-4.4-pm153.2.8.x86_64
libavdevice57-3.4.9-pm153.1.2.x86_64

real    1m15,788s
user    0m2,727s
sys 0m0,613s
~> time rpm -qa libavd\*
libavdevice58_13-4.4-pm153.2.8.x86_64
libavdevice57-3.4.9-pm153.1.2.x86_64

real    0m2,300s
user    0m2,220s
sys 0m0,080s
```

So still with all files in RAM cache the command needs 2.2 seconds of user CPU.

### Effect of rebuilding the database

(Sorry, the locale is `de_DE`)

```text
# ll /var/lib/rpm/
insgesamt 447440
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20901888 28. Jan 20:35 Basenames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     28672 28. Jan 20:35 Conflictname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12189696 28. Jan 20:35 Dirnames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192 27. Jan 21:40 Enhancename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192 22. Jan 22:51 Filetriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     77824 28. Jan 20:35 Group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184320 28. Jan 20:35 Installtid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    319488 28. Jan 20:35 Name
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     94208 28. Jan 20:35 Obsoletename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 409018368 28. Jan 20:35 Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11694080 28. Jan 20:35 Providename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    114688 28. Jan 20:35 Recommendname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1339392 28. Jan 20:35 Requirename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 26. Okt 2014  .rpm.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    634880 28. Jan 20:35 Sha1header
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    360448 28. Jan 20:35 Sigmd5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     20480 27. Jan 21:40 Suggestname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    667648 28. Jan 20:34 Supplementname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192 20. Nov 2018  Transfiletriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192 31. Dez 02:06 Triggername
# rpm --rebuilddb 
# ll /var/lib/rpm/
insgesamt 373392
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16920576  3. Feb 21:26 Basenames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     24576  3. Feb 21:26 Conflictname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7684096  3. Feb 21:26 Dirnames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192  3. Feb 21:26 Enhancename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192  3. Feb 21:26 Filetriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     77824  3. Feb 21:26 Group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    139264  3. Feb 21:26 Installtid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    311296  3. Feb 21:26 Name
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     77824  3. Feb 21:26 Obsoletename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 343470080  3. Feb 21:26 Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10416128  3. Feb 21:26 Providename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    114688  3. Feb 21:26 Recommendname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1204224  3. Feb 21:26 Requirename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    503808  3. Feb 21:26 Sha1header
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    311296  3. Feb 21:26 Sigmd5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     16384  3. Feb 21:26 Suggestname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    647168  3. Feb 21:26 Supplementname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192  3. Feb 21:26 Transfiletriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8192  3. Feb 21:26 Triggername
#
```

Having upgraded to OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 the issue is still there (kernel 5.14.21-150500.55.12-default, rpm-4.14.3-150300.55.1.x86_64):

```sh
> # directly after boot and login, so most likely no data cached
> time rpm -qa >/tmp/rpmlist-poweroff

real    0m58,971s
user    0m3,016s
sys 0m0,472s
> time rpm -qa 'base*'

real    0m2,644s
user    0m2,603s
sys 0m0,040s
> # when the data is in cache, it's mostly CPU-bound
```

So the issue seems to be excessive (useless?) I/O.

Comment: Please try running `sudo rpm --rebuilddb` and check whether it helps.

Comment: Neither `man rpm` nor `rpm --help` do list that option for rpm-4.13.3.

Comment: Well, it's there, it works and you decided not to run it. The official documentation also doesn't count I presume: https://rpm.org/user_doc/db_recovery.html Cheers!

Comment: Did you ever find any reason for the slowness or figure out a way to improve it?

Comment: @bdrx Honestly, If I'd know the answer, I would have added it here

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered by using the verbose flag to rpm `rpm -qa -vvv` that rpm on the OS I am using (RHEL 8) does signature and digest checking when querying all the packages. Adding the `--nodigest` and `--nosignature` flags significantly improved the time for me.

```
rpm -qa --nodigest --nosignature base*
```

Example timings from my system:

```
$ free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
$ time rpm -qa > /dev/null

real: 0m2.944s
user: 0m1.689s
sys:  0m0.163s
$ time rpm -qa > /dev/null

real: 0m1.740s
user: 0m1.644s
sys:  0m0.079s
$ free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
$ time rpm -qa --nodigest --nosignature > /dev/null

real: 0m1.319s
user: 0m0.259s
sys:  0m0.147s
$ time rpm -qa --nodigest --nosignature > /dev/null

real: 0m0.366s
user: 0m0.235s
sys:  0m0.099s
```

Now I just need to discover if there is a way to safely configure the system (maybe edit or override the macros) to set this as the default behavior for `-qa`.

Comment: Would you like to improve your answer by adding these: (1) Actual timing without `--nodigest --nosignature`, (2) After emptying any caches, the timing with those options applied. And just to make sure, (3) After emptying any caches, actual timing without `--nodigest --nosignature`. This is just to "prove"  your findings...